# In ClojureScript, how do I take a string and see if a function with that name exists in the Math object?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I'd like to take a user-supplied string, e.g. `"abs"`, and see whether a function with that name exists in the [`Math` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

So, something like:

```
(.lookup Math "abs") ;; => <function>
(.lookup Math "abdominals") ;; => nil
```

I'd also like to get the function itself, so something like this would work:

```
((.lookup Math "abs") -1) ;; => 1
```

And how can constants be accessed?

```
(.lookup Math "PI") => 3.14159265
```

If it's the same as functions, there has to be a way to distinguish between functions and constants.

I've tried using `.hasOwnProperty`:

```
(print (.hasOwnProperty Math "E"))
```

But that results in errors:

```
TypeError: cljsfiddle.Math is undefined
```

Comment: @adeneo: why we write C/C++, or even C#
 not assembly then? :-)

Comment: use js/Math to access Math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is that `Math` is not accessible. The solution to that is to use `js/Math`.

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (.hasOwnProperty js/Math "E")
true
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (.hasOwnProperty js/Math "Earst")
false
```

Then, to get these properties out of `Math`, `eval` has to be used:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js/eval "Math.min")
#<function min() { [native code for Math.min, arity=2] }
>
ClojureScript:cljs.user> ((js/eval "Math.min") 1 3)
1
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js/eval "Math.E")
2.718281828459045
```

Using `eval` on user-supplied strings is always dangerous, but this can be made be somewhat safe, by first checking `.hasOwnProperty` to ensure you're not running arbitrary code with `eval`. It's still suboptimal, though.

Finally, we can use `number?` and `fn?` to tell the difference between constants and functions:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (number? (js/eval "Math.E"))
true
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (fn? (js/eval "Math.E"))
false
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (number? (js/eval "Math.sin"))
false
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (fn? (js/eval "Math.sin"))
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use js/Math, try on https://himera.herokuapp.com/index.html

```
Himera REPL v0.1.5
cljs.user> js/Math
#<[object Math]>
cljs.user> (.-abs js/Math)
#<function abs() { [native code] }>
cljs.user> (type (.-abs js/Math))
#<function Function() { [native code] }>
cljs.user> (fn? (.-abs js/Math))
true
```

also read https://himera.herokuapp.com/synonym.html

Comment: This works to get beyond the initial error, but apparently we need to use `eval` to get the function or constant out.